ValueError:'rope_scaling' must be a dictionary with two fields, 'type' and 'factor'
When training llama3.1-8B-Instruct model on Amazon sagemaker, the training job fails with the following output:
./usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py:1150: FutureWarning: `resume_download` 
is deprecated and will be removed in version 1.0.0. Downloads always resume when possible. If you want to force a new download, use `force_download=True`.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/train.py", line 85, in <module>
    main()
  File "/workspace/train.py", line 48, in main
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_name, token=use_auth_token)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/auto/configuration_auto.py", line 1124, in from_pretrained
    return config_class.from_dict(config_dict, **unused_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py", line 764, in from_dict
    config = cls(**config_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/llama/configuration_llama.py", line 160, in __init__
    self._rope_scaling_validation()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/llama/configuration_llama.py", line 180, in _rope_scaling_validation
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: `rope_scaling` must be a dictionary with with two fields, `type` and `factor`, got {'factor': 8.0, 'low_freq_factor': 1.0, 'high_freq_factor': 4.0, 'original_max_position_embeddings': 8192, 'rope_type': 'llama3'}

I've tried changing the config.rope_scaling and applying it to the model but it doesn't work. This is the code snippet where I change the config:
# Load model configuration
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_name, token=use_auth_token)

# Modify the rope_scaling config
config.rope_scaling = {
    "type": "llama3",
    "factor": 8.0
}

# Initialize the model with the modified config
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(modek_name, token=use_auth_token, config=config)


try to print print(config.rope_scaling) after you set new rope scaling to check if its set properly. sometimes, old configurations or cached model files can cause unexpected issues. You can clear the cache and reinitialize the environment.

I just faced the same error using Llama 3.1 with transformers-4.41.0. It was resolved by upgrading:
pip install --upgrade transformers

With transformers-4.44.2 everything runs perfectly. See the related GitHub issue for more details.
